# Magento success page order number not showing

Tags: php, magento, numbers

I have a simple question, what could cause this:

**At magento success page there are no order number**

Its just empty, what could cause this problem?

Order id are loaded by this line

```
$this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())
```

Code are loaded by manabee ordershare module.
Also this shop have many modules and code changes.

So I need as many as possible ways you can suggest why this is happening. I will check them all.

Comment: What does it output if you `var_dump($this->getOrderId())`? Also what is the class rendering that template (`var_dump(get_class($this))`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meanbee_OrderShare_Block_Ordershare` extends `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success` so it should work as the standard success page block. The `getOrderId` metod comes from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success`. I recomend you check the exception.log, system.log and php error log, maybe you have an error. I allways recomend to read core files, then you will know how it works.
I think that you should check what you have in chechout session at first.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: What was the problem...?